# How can I re-open or take a question off-hold?

Tags: support, re-open

What is the proper course of action if you think a question (not necessarily your own) was wrongly closed or put on hold? Just bring it up here? Or is there some page you're meant to go to to vote to re-open?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can post a request [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6424/requests-for-reopen-votes) or, once you [earn enough reputation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges), you can vote to reopen on the question page itself.